# C# Invoke Failing on Thread Function

Tags: c#, multithreading, inheritance, invoke

I'm using a timer to regularly read-in a log file and post certain contents to a textbox in a Windows Form Application I'm developing in C#. I do this by sending a string to set_textbox_thread which posts  the text (s) to the appropriate textbox (tbc) in the else below. The code below works in the practice application I built. However, the same code runs, but fails to update my textbox in the full application I'm building. It seems to be failing on the Invoke statement, which fails to call set_textbox_thread again. My theory is that, because my full application has a more complex set of controls, I am not calling Invoke via the correct control. I've tried calling it via "this" the parent panel, the parent form, and the button that triggers set_textbox_thread, and am dealing with the same outcome. Two questions:

1. Which control should I call Invoke under?
2. Is there a way to retrieve "the thread that owns the controls underlying windows handle? Can I do this through the Controls.Owner method?
3. I have tried making this Invoke call using try/catch, but am unable to retrieve an error message in the catch. Any ideas how to resolve the issue this way?

Thanks in advance!

```
private delegate void stringDelegate(string s);        
private void set_textbox_thread(string s)
    {
        TextBox tbc = get_thread_tb();

        if (tbc.InvokeRequired)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invoke Required");
            stringDelegate sd = new stringDelegate(set_textbox_thread);
            **this.Invoke(sd, new object[] {s });**
            MessageBox.Show("Invoke Completed");
        }
        else
        {
```

Comment: What class is set_textbox_thread contained within?  The Form?

Comment: What does the rest of set_textbox_thread do?  you've only posted half the code...

Comment: You haven't shown anything that *could* work (i.e. nothing that actually updates a text box).  Really hard to tell you how to fix it ...

Comment: Looks like the code that you posted above is missing a few pieces.

Answer (score 0):

1) It doesn't matter what control you invoke under; there is only one UI thread and any control to marshal the call back to that UI thread.

2) what could you possibly do with this thread?

3) not much detail there.  How do you know you have error messages?  And what do you mean by "error messages"

Answer (score 0):

Call invoke on the text box instead:

```
tbc.Invoke(sd, new object[] {s });
```